# Calculate $X$ of a math problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

I am trying to learn some more math and I got stuck on this:

$$\frac{0.2}{X} = 140$$

How do I calculate $X$?

**EDIT**

Sorry I meant to calculate $$\frac{28}{X} = 140$$

So that $X = 0.2$, but how do I calculate it?

Comment: You mean $\frac{0.2}{X}=140$ ?

Comment: hm, yes probably, 0,2 divided by X = 140 "What is X?"

Comment: are you aware of the fact that you are allowed to multiply both sides of an equality by the same number?

Comment: No, i'm not used to math, I'm very bad at it

Comment: note to some readers,   there are parts in the world where the decimal point is symbolized by a comma instead of a period.  I suspect Hannes is in such a part of the world

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}\frac{0.2}{X}=140&\Rightarrow \frac{0.2}{X}\times X=140\times X\\&\Rightarrow 0.2=140X\\&\Rightarrow 0.2\times\frac{1}{140}=140X\times\frac{1}{140}\\&\Rightarrow \frac{0.2}{140}=X\\&\Rightarrow X=\frac{0.2\times 10}{140\times 10}=\frac{2}{1400}=\frac{1}{700}.\end{align}$$

P.S. 1 : Multiplying the both sides of $$\frac{0.2}{X}=140$$by X gives us
$$\frac{0.2}{X}\times X=140\times X$$
i.e.
$$0.2=140X.$$

P.S. 2 : Multiplying the both sides of 
$$\frac{28}{X}=140$$
by $X$ gives us
$$\frac{28}{X}\times X=140\times X$$
i.e.
$$28=140X.$$
Then, multiplying the both sides by $\frac{1}{140}$ gives us
$$28\times\frac{1}{140}=140X\times\frac{1}{140}$$
i.e.
$$\frac{28}{140}=X.$$

Then, we have
$$X=\frac{28}{140}=\frac{28}{28\times 5}=\frac{1}{5}=0.2.$$

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you wrote, my ,math is very bad. could you explain it a bit more?

Comment: @HannesBrolinLagerstedt: I added a bit. Can you understand that?

Comment: Yes I understand now, thank you